# Getting image width on image load fails on IE

Tags: javascript, image, image-loading

I have a image resizer function that resize images proportional. On every image load a call this function with image and resize if its width or height is bigger than my max width and max height. I can get img.width and img.height in FF Chrome Opera Safari but IE fails. How can i handle this?

Let me explain with a piece of code.

```
<img src="images/img01.png" onload="window.onImageLoad(this, 120, 120)" />

function onImageLoad(img, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
     var width = img.width; // Problem is in here
     var height = img.height // Problem is in here
}
```

In my highligted lines img.width don't work on IE series.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `img.currentStyle.width` ??

Comment: @Fatih Suggestion: don't mix JavaScript in your HTML like that (the `onload` attribute). Dynamically attach event handlers in JS alone.

Comment: Works fine in IE 8 over here: http://jsbin.com/ehovu4/#noedit

Comment: I have find the problem. Stupid IE cannnot calculate display: none; image's width and height. I have set images visibility: hidden; then everything worked but until images load horizontal and vertical scroll bars is seeing.

Comment: +1 for the `display:none` hint

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't use `width` and `height`. Use `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` instead. These provide the image unscaled pixel dimensions from the image file and will work across browsers.

Comment: IMHO, This is the best answer on the page and _should_ be the accepted answer.

Comment: In IE 8, you can get the natural width by creating an Image instance, setting the src to the desired image, and grabbing that instance's dimensions:

`function onImageLoad(img, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
    var ghost = new Image();
    ghost.src = img.src;
    var width = ghost.width;
    var height = ghost.height
    ...
}`

Answer (score 4):

Man, I was looking for this for 2 days. Thanks.

I'm using jQuery, but it doesnt matter. Problem is related to javascript in IE.

My previous code:

```
var parentItem = $('<div/>')
   .hide();      // sets display to 'none'

var childImage = $('<img/>')
   .attr("src", src)
   .appendTo(parentItem)   // sets parent to image
   .load(function(){
      alert(this.width);  // at this point image is not displayed, because parents display parameter is set to 'none' - IE gives you value '0'
   });
```

This is working in FF, Opera and Safari but no IE. I was getting '0' in IE.

Workaround for me:

```
var parentItem = $('<div/>')
   .hide();

var childImage = $('<img/>')
   .attr("src", src)
   .load(function(){
      alert(this.width);  // at this point image css display is NOT 'none'  - IE gives you correct value
      childImage.appendTo(parentItem);   // sets parent to image
   });
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved it (because it's the only js on the site I didn't want to use a library).

```
    var imageElement = document.createElement('img');
    imageElement.src = el.href; // taken from a link cuz I want it to work even with no script
    imageElement.style.display      = 'none';

    var imageLoader = new Image();
    imageLoader.src = el.href;
    imageLoader.onload = function() {
        loaderElement.parentElement.removeChild(loaderElement);
        imageElement.style.position     = 'absolute';
        imageElement.style.top          = '50%';
        imageElement.style.left         = '50%';
        // here using the imageLoaders size instead of the imageElement..
        imageElement.style.marginTop    = '-' + (parseInt(imageLoader.height) / 2) + 'px';
        imageElement.style.marginLeft   = '-' + (parseInt(imageLoader.width) / 2) + 'px';
        imageElement.style.display      = 'block';
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because IE can't calculate width and height of `display: none` images. Use `visibility: hidden` instead.

Comment: FYI, the working sample/failed sample links result in HTTP 404 errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 function onImageLoad(img, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
   var width = img.width; // Problem is in here
   var height = img.height // Problem is in here
   if (height==0  && img.complete){
       setTimeOut(function(){onImageLoad(img, maxWidth, maxHeight);},50);
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var screenW = screen.width;
    var screenH = screen.height;
    //alert( screenW );
    function checkFotoWidth( img, maxw )
    {
        if( maxw==undefined)
            maxw = 200;
        var imgW = GetImageWidth(img.src);
        var imgH = GetImageHeight(img.src);
            //alert(GetImageWidth(img.src).toString()); // img.width); // objToString(img));
        if (imgW > maxw || (img.style.cursor == "hand" && imgW == maxw))
        {
            if (imgW > screenW) winW = screenW;
            else winW = imgW;

            if (imgH > screenH) winH = screenH;
            else winH = imgH;

            img.width=maxw;
            img.style.cursor = "pointer";

            img.WinW = winW;
            img.WinH = winH;
            //alert("winW : " + img.WinW);
            img.onclick = function() { openCenteredWindow("Dialogs/ZoomWin.aspx?img=" + this.src, this.WinW, this.WinH, '', 'resizable=1'); }
            img.alt = "Klik voor een uitvergroting :: click to enlarge :: klicken Sie um das Bild zu vergrössern";
            //alert("adding onclick);
        }
    }

    function GetImageWidth(imgSrc) 
    {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = imgSrc;
        return img.width;
    } 

    function GetImageHeight(imgSrc) 
    {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = imgSrc;
        return img.height;
    }
```

Comment: it's also best to first hide your image, then display it once you resized it. Otherwise you'll get flickering effects with large images.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this:

```
function onImageLoad(img, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
   var width, height;
   if ('currentStyle' in img) {
     width = img.currentStyle.width;
     height = img.currentStyle.height;
   }
   else {
     width = img.width;
     height = img.height;
   }
   // whatever
}
```

*edit* — and apparently if I were to try that I'd learn it doesn't work :-)  OK, well "width" and "height" definitely seem to be attributes of `<img>` elements as far as IE is concerned.  Maybe the problem is that the "load" event is firing for the element at the wrong time.  To check whether that's the case, I would then try this:

```
function onImageLoad(img, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
   var width, height;
   var i = new Image();
   i.onload = function() {
     width = i.width; height = i.height;
     // ... stuff you want to do ...
   };
   i.src = img.href;
}
```

Comment: it returns "auto". But I need the exact width and height, I mean the dimensions

Comment: Oh crap :-)  Well, that's IE for you.  Let me think about it for a sec.

Comment: How about `offsetWidth`/`offsetHeight`? I suspect those will work even with width/height return `auto`.

Comment: @Phrogz offsetWidth/offsetHeight returns 0

Comment: @Fatih That seems very broken then. Are the images surely loaded? I would personally hack it by adding a `setTimeout(...,1)` kicked off from the `load` event to give it one more chance to re-layout the page before asking for the dimensions.

Comment: We can be sure images are loaded if IE doesn't lie to us because the function is calling on image load. I guess, I have done with it. check the question's third comment that was written by me.

Comment: problem is setting the images display: none; IE cannot calculate the displayed none image's dimensions

Answer (score -1):

```
getDisplay().getImage().setUrl(imgURL);
final Image img = new Image(imgURL);
int w=img.getWidth();
int h=img.getHeight();
```

Comment: The question is about JavaScript