# How can I get width and height of SVG on Image.load in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg

It works fine everywhere but not in IE 11 (I have not tested other IE versions yet).

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){

   alert( 'img: ' + img.width + 'x' + img.height + 
          '  natural: ' + img.naturalWidth + 'x' + img.naturalHeight );

};
img.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b5/Boeing-Logo.svg';
```

JSFiddle: 
<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncgvj/1/)</kbd>

Result:

`img: 121x30   natural: 121x30` - Real browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, ...)

`img: 0x0   natural: 0x0` - IE 11

There is a similar question here: [Getting image width on image load fails on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472086/getting-image-width-on-image-load-fails-on-ie)

None of the solutions from those answers work for svg.

Is there a way to get the width and height of a svg file loaded with Image() in Internet Explorer 11?

**Note:** I am looking for a solution without having to add the element to the DOM for measuring, as I want to avoid any unnecessary re-flow/repaint.

Comment: What version of IE are you testing for?

Comment: You can wrap a div or something around it and when it fails you can use the parent width and height.

Comment: @Erwinus This means It will have to be added to the DOM beforehand, which is not ideal.

Comment: I've also had the same need, but could not solve it.

Comment: @san.chez: Dunno what you going to do with it (what is your goal) but I think you need to add it to the DOM anyway. Maybe it is not measured because it is not visible like most of the DOM objects that are not visible.

Comment: Can you change the accepted answer to this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23256878/238753

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This code works in IE11:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    document.body.appendChild(this);
    alert( 'img: ' + this.offsetWidth + 'x' + this.offsetHeight);
    document.body.removeChild(this);
};
img.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b5/Boeing-Logo.svg';
```

And yes - this solution is not ideal.

Comment: This solution worked for me. The problem with the accepted solution to use `$.get` is that can fall victim to CORS Access-Control headers.

Comment: This is the best solution! Thanks @dimacpp!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think you can access the SVG content if it is loaded as a `src` attribute, and not inline.

One solution might be to change the way the SVG is loaded, so perhaps load via AJAX, and then append to the document by another means. This gives you a chance to have full access the the SVG source before adding to the document...

```
/* use ajax (and in this example jQuery) to get SVG as XML */
$.get('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b5/Boeing-Logo.svg', function(svgxml){

    /* now with access to the source of the SVG, lookup the values you want... */
    var attrs = svgxml.documentElement.attributes;
    alert( 'img: ' + attrs.width.value + 'x' + attrs.height.value );

    /* do something with the svg, like add it to the document for example... */
    $(document.body).append(document.importNode(svgxml.documentElement,true));

}, "xml");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncgvj/6/)

This example has used jQuery, and loads the content of the SVG as xml, but you could do it in many ways following the same principle, for example loading as text string, and accessing with regular jQuery methods, or without jQuery at all.

The moral of the story, is that if you load it via AJAX, you can get a reference to the content of the SVG and have more control over it before it gets added to the page.

Answer (score -1):

In html5 standard:

> The IDL attributes width and height must return the rendered width and height of the image, in CSS pixels, if the image is being rendered, and is being rendered to a visual medium; or else the intrinsic width and height of the image, in CSS pixels, if the image is available but not being rendered to a visual medium; or else 0, if the image is not available. [LINK](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-img-width)

If img not rendered then IE reserves the right to display 0. And it seems he is doing this.

With .naturalWidth and .naturalHeight similar situation.

Comment: According to the text you posted, if the image is not rendered to a visual medium but is available (= loaded), then the browser should return the intrinsic width and height, not zero.