# IE cannot get size of image in xml+svg format?

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, internet-explorer, svg

I can get `width` and `height` of Image in Chrome however it returns 0 in IE 11. If the format is `data:image/png` it works without any problem. Btw image is shown in IE without problem but I need size to adjust canvas size according to Image.[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-dream-m9244) Below code works in Chrome but not in IE.

Question is how can I get size of image which is svg+xml based in IE?

```
  let img1 = new Image();
  img1.onload = () => console.log(img1.width);
  img1.src = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,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`
```

Chrome return size: 126

IE return size: 0

Comment: use max-width or min-width for IE, and the best solution is dont use IE its not safe and have no support .

Comment: I cannot even reach img1 in onload function. when I try to `console.log(img1)` IE log empty line.

Comment: IE is terrible when it comes to SVG support. Just use Edge. No reason to be using IE anymore these days...

Comment: the thing is, your code fiddle is not even working on IE or edge, on chrome it works fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822921/how-can-i-get-width-and-height-of-svg-on-image-load-in-ie-11

Comment: Yes thanks both of you!! @martin_borman